# android - Тормозит SnackBar

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

При клике на `FoatingActionButton (FAB)` должен срабатывать `SnackBar`. Вот разметка, когда все работало плавно:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="#DD6E19"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewA"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Но стоит мне в `RelativeLayout` (с `id=viewA`) в `background` вместо цвета `#424242` поставить ссылку `@drawable/header` на картинку, то при нажатии на `FAB` тормозит сама анимация нажатия и анимация `SnackBar`-a.

Что не так?

Comment: Картинка, видать, тяжелая. Попробуйте её уменьшить

Comment: что это за drawable - `@drawable/header`?

Comment: Уже все) Это была 2-мегабайтная картинка hd в стиле material design))